# Migrating an old question

Tags: discussion, migration

I was looking at some old questions and ran across [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/was-the-boston-tea-party-about-a-tax-cut-or-a-tax-raise?rq=1) about the Boston Tea Party.  It's a good question and it has a good answer, but it really belongs on History.SE rather than Politics.SE.

The question is almost 5 years old at this point, so should it be migrated? Is there any point to dealing with now it given its age?

If the answer is yes, how do I go about doing that? Flag it or VTC?

What's the general policy on this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2):

This Q has been raised numerous times on Meta.SE: [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152597/), [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76702/), [three](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136537/), and the consensus is that, migrating old Q's is generally a bad idea, its downsides overweight its benefit.

Just VTC, and if a new SE site has emerged since then, nothing prevents you from asking it there, providing the link to the existing Q here.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to have a community manager migrate it at this point. Site mods have a 60 day window, same as close-migrate votes.

You'd need a super compelling reason to get it moved at this point. Just leave it.

See [Migrate to *any* site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86928/migrate-to-any-site)

Answer (score 0):

You're right that it's a better fit on history, but it's not wildly off-topic on politics, either.

I don't see the harm in just leaving the question as-is. It's a useful question with useful answers that is not accumulating spam, bad answers, too many comments, or other unwanted content. That question was posted almost five years ago and, arguably, should have been closed five years ago. But it wasn't, and I think it's happy where as it is ;-)